# Xamarin NetStandard Android sfChart DateTimeStripLine not displayed?

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, syncfusion, .net-standard

This is fairly specific (as the title suggests).

I've recently ported my Xamarin Forms app to NETStandard, and now my sfChart DateTimeStripLine are not visible on Android.

Things show up more-or-less fine on UWP, so I don't think I've introduced regressions.

Anyone else having similar experiences?  Has anyone successfully used ChartStripLine on NET Standard?

Comment: probably need to throw in a fallback for framework since I believe the Syncfusion Controls aren't .netstandard compliant yet.

Comment: It would need to be either 4.5 or 4.6.1

Comment: actually - I think I'm using the fallback already (I forgot about that.  NetStandard hasn't been an easy ride so far).  The graphs do work and display, I'm just missing this one small feature...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have prepared a sample using DateTimeStripline in SfChart with .Net Standard 1.3 and it’s working fine in this [sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/XamarinSample-285135782). If still you face the problem, please provide Stripline related code snippet, it would be helpful to provide  better solution.

Comment: Thanks a tonne - having a working sample should help me narrow down what the problem is!

Answer (score 0):

So, finally figured out the issue:

The StripLines declared in XAML work fine, but binding to a StripLineCollection did not (android only).  Unfortunately, declaring in XAML is not a particularly useful option.

To fix/workaround, declare StripLine in XAML like so:

```
<chart:DateTimeAxis x:Name="TheTimeAxis" ...>
  <chart:DateTimeAxis.StripLines>
    <!-- Empty def requires at least one item to be used
         This creates container to fill in ViewModel.
         Fixes dissappearing StripLines bug on android -->
    <chart:DateTimeStripLine WidthType="Day" Width ="1"  
                                         Start="09/28/2017">

    </chart:DateTimeStripLine >
  </chart:DateTimeAxis.StripLines>
```

Then, in the code behind access the named axis, pull out the striplines and modify to your hearts content.

```
// Workaround Android: Our StripLines do not appear to be
// refreshing when bound from XAML.  To fix we create in XAML,
// then retrieve the existing collection and pass that to the
// viewmodel for modification
DateTimeAxis sl = this.TheTimeAxis;
var slc = sl.StripLines;
```